# How to print ODF files using java print API

Tags: java, printing, doc, odf

How do i print an ODF file using the java print api framework? i can't seem to find any info on printing odf file using the java print api.

java accept postscript and convert it into doc for printing.

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("example.ps");
                        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, psFlavor, null);
                        pj.print(doc, aset);
```

how do i do the same for ODF file?

Comment: Is javax.print.* a firm requirement.  Maybe you could try `Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File("example.odf"));` instead?  Also there is https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling#DocumentPrinter which gives example for OpenOffice type files.

Comment: @demongolem thanks for your response, i change to system to print pdf instead of ODF file.